Cant figure out how to write to a notepad file on Desktop using python
Basically, I want a simple python code to ask user to input 3 different answers to questions, and then to just write those inputs to a notepad file. The code I have been trying to use is:
user_input1 = input("What is your name: ")
user_input2 = input("What is your age: ")
user_input3 = input("What is your city: ")
with open("my_file.txt", "w") as f:
    results = ({user_input1}, {user_input2}, {user_input3})
    f.write,([results])

    f.close()

I am a newbie (really new) to python and am learning as I go along as well as taking college courses for learning python ETC.
Any help / hints to what is going wrong would be greatly appreciated.
I have tried searching on google for every error that came up, this is the only version of my code that successfully "Finished with code 0" in the interpreter. Yet still doesn't write to the notepad file. I do have a notepad file on the computer with this program and code etc.
I currently have both the notepad file I need it to write to and the python code file in a folder on my desktop and have been running the interpreter from in there, along with trying to run the code in there as well.
Thanks for any help!
Justin

Problem 1:  The comma after write is incorrect.  Remove it.  Problem 2: write expects a string argument (inside then ( ... ) ) but you are giving it a list.  The str function converts something to a string ...

I see a few issues try running the following:
user_input1 = input("What is your name: ")
user_input2 = input("What is your age: ")
user_input3 = input("What is your city: ")

# Open a file and write the inputs
with open("my_file.txt", "w") as f:
    # Create a formatted string with the inputs
    results = f"{user_input1}, {user_input2}, {user_input3}"
    # Write the formatted string to the file
    f.write(results)

You want results to be a string not a tuple and also f.write,([results]) shouldn't have the comma or the brackets -> f.write(results). Also the close() isn't needed. This will save the inputs to a text file which can be open with notepad or any text editor. If you are wanting to save it as a tuple then like adjust the results line to be:
results = f"({user_input1}, {user_input2}, {user_input3})"


Thank you! Agreed, and noted about the close as well! , just beginning Python!

instead of f.write,([results]), you can instead use f.write(results). The f.close() is also unnneccesary

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Notwithstanding the issues pointed out by other contributors, you need to think about the value of writing your file in that naive format. Ask yourself how you would read the data from the file. What would happen if the input included a space? Maybe consider CSV format.
Something like this:
OUTPUT_FILE = "my_file.txt"
COMMA = ","

def get_input(prompt: str) -> str:
    while True:
        v = input(prompt)
        if COMMA in v:
            print("\aInput cannot contain comma")
        else:
            return v

user_input1 = get_input("What is your name: ")
user_input2 = get_input("What is your age: ")
user_input3 = get_input("What is your city: ")

with open(OUTPUT_FILE, "w") as output:
    row = COMMA.join([user_input1, user_input2, user_input3])
    output.write(row)

Of course, if you do want output in CSV format you should probably be using the built-in csv module

Thank you, I plan on changin to csv in time, this was just a small project to start me learning Python!
